# sudo apt-get update 16.04LTS

Tags: package-management, 16.04, updates

I installed 16.04LTS. When I run the `sudo apt-get update` command this is the error I get:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

Please help me with the same.

Comment: Was it a fresh install of 16.04? Are you sure it is 16.04? `saucy` is 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled the saucy-updates repository, however clearly the above two links don't make any sense, since saucy (13.10) can't match with xenial (16.04).

1. You need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list/` and comment out the two lines that caused you to get the `E: Failed to fetch` error messages by inserting a `#` character at the beginning of both of the lines that start with: `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/`.

   From the terminal run the following command to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list/` with nano text editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
2. Update your software sources.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

Comment: `sudo nano` is not good. It will create a root owned file in the user directory.  And next time nano will throw errors. `sudo -H nano` will do.

Comment: @Pilot6 That's a very interesting comment because I have been using `sudo nano` without the `-H` (`--historylog`) option on multiple instances of Ubuntu on different computers and that never once happened to me. I wish I could tell you more, but I don't know why it's like that on my computers.

Comment: I had some problems with it. Maybe now `-H` is default for `sudo`.

Comment: Oh, and `-H` is not `--historylog`. You need to look into `man sudo`, not `man nano` ;-) @karel

Comment: If you can replicate this behavior in 16.04 or in any currently supported *buntu OS running in a virtual machine, this would be a great subject for a question.

Comment: I just typed `man nano` and what I got was `-H (--historylog) Log  search  and replace strings to ~/.nano_history, so they can be retrieved in later sessions, if nanorc support is available.`

Comment: Type `man sudo` and you will see what I am talking about. In this case it is `sudo` parameter, not `nano`. If you typed `nano -H`, then it is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42478/discussion-between-karel-and-pilot6).